Charge and parity in a Kitaev wire
I'm having trouble understanding the two degenerate ground states of the kitaev wire in the topological phase. As far as I understand the difference between the two ground states is in the parity: one having all paired cooper pairs, and the other has the addition of the non-local zero-mode composed of the two Majorana states creating an odd-parity state.
If it indeed the case:

where does the additional fermion come from, when we transition between the two states? and how can we transition between them?

If this non-local fermion is not charge, how can it contribute to the fractional Josephson current?


